# How to remove all networking packages from ubuntu

Tags: networking, package-management, lubuntu

I'm creating a customised version of Lubuntu, which I would like to have absolutely no networking/ethernet/wifi/bluetooth capability at all. I tried removing the network manager & bluetooth packages, with Synaptic, but the OS is still able to reach the internet.

Can anyone advise which packages would need to be removed to completely disable all internet/wifi/bluetooth connections..?
Thanks

Comment: You'd have to disabled the relevant modules in the kernel.

Comment: While you may be able to rebuild a kernel that has absolutely no hardware network interface support, you cannot remove all network support entirely, and still have a functional system. The loopback interface, and TCP/IP, UDP, etc… are still required for the system to function properly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies both. Is there any way of maybe doing some kind of tweak to the OS to deny internet use without having to rebuild kernel...?

Comment: You can deny internet access by disabling the kernel modules for you hard ware, turn off wifi or pull the wire, iptables, network manager, your router ....

Comment: Thanks Panther, if anyone could point me the way to disable a kernel module for this I'd be very grateful, will try to research how to anyway. The objective is - is to have an OS that no application could find any route to the internet (bluetooth/wifi/ethernet) against wishes of user

Comment: List the modules in use with lsmod , blacklist the ones related to your networking / bluetooth hardware - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules